# My sql time range selection

Tags: mysql, database

My table

```
starttime   |   endtime  |   id

10:30            11:30        1
11:30            12:30        2
14:30            16:30        3
15:30            16:30        4
```

I need to find the id in a given time slot for example 
say

```
10:30 to 13:30 should give me o/p 1 2    
11:30 to 16:30 should give o/p 2 3 4
```

The statement I am using

```
select id from table where STR_TO_DATE(starttime,'%h:%i')>='10:30' and STR_TO_DATE(endtime,'%h:%i')<='22:30';
```

it gives me only 1 and 2

I am not able to get the correct output what am I doing wrong here?
Note start and end time in varchar

EDIT-

If I wanted to selectthe id's between 10:30 to 12:30 I use this below command

```
select id from table where  STR_TO_DATE(starttime,'%H:%i')>='10:30' and STR_TO_DATE(endtime,'%H:%i')<='12:30';
```

This gives me only id 1 .. but not giving me 2, If i change 12:30 to 12:40 it gives me 1 & 2.BUt I am using less or equal so it should give me both the id's right? Why its not working like that?

Comment: just curious, what `o/p` stand  for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> STR_TO_DATE(starttime,'%h:%i')

You are using the format %h which according to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is for:

> Hour (01..12)

Essentially, everything above 12 is invalid (Returns NULL).
And, you gave values above 12 to those ids.

Use the specifier

> %H

for hours in the format 00 - 23

or the specifier

> %k

for hours 0 - 23.